# How to provision the custom list form using PnP Provisioning Engine?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, pnp, pnp-provision

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/provisioning-console-application-sample) article for provisioning Sites for SharePoint Online through console application.

Now, In the base site, I have created the custom list and a new custom list form for the list. I want to provision the same site to my newly created site collection. **But** when I provision, my new site does not contain any custom list form.

**My question is,** How to provision the custom list form using PnP Provisioning Engine?

Comment: Have you tried this? Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp -Handlers Lists

Comment: Is there any alternative using C# code for this?

Comment: Are you trying to provision sites with particular list/libraries and Is there any particular reasons you would need to do this with C#?

Comment: @AakashMaurya Yes, there's plain PowerShell code (which I believe can be easily ported to C# as it uses the same CSOM API):

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/82b15a/deploy-custom-list-forms-using-powershell-in-sharepoint-2013/